# POST parameters with Jquery AJAX and ASPX Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send an Ajax post to an ASPX page and although this exact same process works with classic ASP, my Request.Form object is empty when POSTing to an ASPX page.

Here is my Ajax call (I am using ajaxSetup to set URL, encoding, etc):

```
$.ajax({
        data: '{"Command":"GetGeoLocations"}',
        success: function (responseData) {
            alert("Success " + responseData);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert( "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Here is that ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            url: "Ajax/AjaxForm.aspx",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST"
        });
```

Here is Firebug's POST parameter:
[image]

Here is the Request.Form object on the .NET side:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you have extra quotes for data attribute.

```
$.ajax({
        data: {"Command":"GetGeoLocations"},
        success: function (responseData) {
            alert("Success " + responseData);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert( "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

dataType T should be capital,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            url: "Ajax/AjaxForm.aspx",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST"
        });
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Comment: Nope, still get an empty Request.Form object.

Comment: @ElJay, the problem is dataType T should be capital. Check and respond

Comment: Thank you sir.  That worked, that typo was a novice mistake.  Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
data: JSON.stringify({"Command":"GetGeoLocations"})
```

Comment: Nope, still get an empty Request.Form object.